# Whenever I plugged my monitor to my laptop the display the background image stays in the same resolution

Tags: screen

My HP Mini is having a problem when plugged into a monitor with high resolution. the problem is the background image stays the same resolution of my laptop which is 1024 x 576 thus leaving blank black portion on the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to the menu-system-monitors and then changing the aspect ratio(screen size) from there? It should work and has worked for me in the past.

Comment: i've already tried still no effects i need to ix to fix these because i need my laptop for presentations.

Comment: does your laptop correctly detect plugged in monitors, if so from the monitors admin area you should be able to select the desired monitor and change the aspect ratio, I have no idea how else you can make this work.